# Random guided graph network

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to create a random guided network in Python using NetworkX library. I have two separate files: (1) contains the list of buildings in a city along with their coordinates and (2) contains the list of stations in that city along with their coordinates. The buildings and stations are spread all over the city. I want to create a random network for a given number of buildings in such a way that each edge in the network gets signals from at least one station (or each edge has at least one station close to it). One station can be close to more than one edge, e.g., in the middle of two edges. I am not sure how can I generate a network of randomly selected buildings where the aforementioned conditions meet. The following figure is an example of the type of the desired network.

[network figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bck8u.png)

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm 1

```
- Create the *minimum spanning tree* for all the buildings
- Remove all edges that are not close enough to a station
- Remove any buildings that are now unconnected
- IF more than required number of buildings remain, remove buildings at random until required number reached
- ELSE IF fewer than required building number remain
    - WHILE too few buildings
         - Select random unconnected building
              - LOOP over other other buildings
                  - IF link between random and loop buildings is near a station
                        - Add building(s) and link
```

Algorithm 2

```
- Randomize building order
- While building count < required
  - Loop B1 over buildings
  - Loop B2 over buildings
  - Loop S over stations
  - IF link B1-B2 close enough to S
       Add buildings and link
```

Algorithm 2 does not produce such 'pretty' graphs, but is simpler to implement.  Here is how I would do it, in C++

```
void cSolution::solve()
{
    for (auto &b1 : vBuilding)
    {
        for (auto &b2 : vBuilding)
        {
            if (b1.first == b2.first && b1.second == b2.second)
                continue;
            for (auto &s : vStation)
            {
                // check distance from station to link between b1 and b2
                if (
                    geo::distance(
                        geo::line_t({b1, b2}),
                        s) < myMinDistance)
                {
                    
                    add(b1);
                    add(b2);
                    add(geo::line_t({b1, b2}));
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( isEnough() )
                break;
        }
        if (isEnough() )
            break;
    }
}
```

The output look like this ( blue: building, red:station, black:link )

[image]

The complete code for this application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/bsha

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To find that if a station is close enough, do I need to use the distance from a point to line or any other better approach could be used?

Comment: Further, would not be computationally time expensive to creating a minimum spanning tree for all the buildings? I was thinking that if there exists an approach where we initially select the buildings and stations randomly, but this randomness is guided in a way that buildings and stations are close enough that meet the desired constraints.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate the algorithm 2 a bit? And with these three loops, do you mean nested loops?

Comment: I have posted a complete implementation in C++ of algorithm 2.